# How to remove MODIS LST scenes from image collection that have no unmasked pixels in study area?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I am trying to get image collection of MODIS daily LST for monsoon season for a region that often has cloudy days.
Filtering MODIS collection with filterBounds seems unable to remove scenes that have no pixel in study area.

First, I checked them with printing number of scenes in each collection

```
// Boundary
var DMDP = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(90.24, 23.59, 90.62, 24.00);
Map.centerObject(DMDP);

// Filtered by boundary
var terra_filtered = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-06-01', '2021-09-30'))
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filterBounds(DMDP);
print(terra_filtered);

// Not filtered by boundary
var terra = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-06-01', '2021-09-30'))
  .select('LST_Day_1km');
print(terra); // Both image collection yeilds same number of images
```

Then, I checked if there are images which does not contain any pixel, e.g., I checked the first image of the collection and found that the image is empty. To be sure, I counted the pixels and it was confirmed - it does not have any pixel.

```
// First image
var monsoon = terra.first();
var visparams = {min: 13000.0, max: 16500.0, palette: ['green', 'yellow', 'red']};
Map.addLayer(monsoon.clip(DMDP), visparams, 'monsoon'); // No pixel visible in study area

// Print number of pixels to check if visual inspection is right
var pixels = monsoon.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: DMDP,
  scale: 500,
});
print('Pixels:', pixels);
```

What could be the possible ways to discard the zero pixel scenes from the image collection, other then the filterBounds? Also, why does filterBounds do not work in this case?

[Link to GEE code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e45b2cbd8ca6818ce61b348276747152)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!
I wrote a function to clip the scenes with study area and counted pixels of the scene. I had some hiccup there - I had to access value of dictionary, which was in list; then access the counted value from the list using its index.

Then, all I had to do was filter the image collection with pixel_count>0.
Do let me know if you have better way to do this

```
// Function to clip scenes
var clipped = function (img) {
    img = img.clip(DMDP);
    var pixels = img.reduceRegion({
          reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
          scale: 1000
       });
    pixels = pixels.values(['LST_Day_1km']).get(0)
    return img
      .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end'])
      .set('pixel_count', pixels)
      ;
};
// Remove null scenes by filtering the images with zero number of pixels
var clip_monsoon = terra.map(clipped)
  .filter(ee.Filter.gt('pixel_count', 0));
print (clip_monsoon)
```

[Link to final GEE code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/22eaf78bd1c45fc7aa394d9dc0eddc30)